# Part of SO seems to think there is no election

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-election

This is very much an edge case, and probably not worth bothering about, but I thought I'd report it.

Increasing the number past the current election (https://stackoverflow.com/election/10) in the url (https://stackoverflow.com/election/11) leads you to a page which says:

> There are no active community moderator elections at the moment. Below is a historical record of all elections to date:

Which at the time of posting is not correct.

This also seems to work for any number that is not between 1 and 10 inclusive (first election to current election).

[image]

Comment: maybe that url hits the server at some point in the future?

Comment: It also works for /0.

Comment: @MEE It works for [999999999](https://stackoverflow.com/election/999999999) also

Comment: Is the "bad" URL (https://stackoverflow.com/election/11 or so on) actually linked anywhere in an "official" context, such that it could reasonably trick someone into thinking there is not a current election? If not, then I don't think this is much of a problem. Of course it would be strictly better if it got fixed than if it didn't, but it's presumably not causing any harm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Links to non-existent elections will now result in a 404!  So the message you were seeing in error is no longer a problem!

Comment: hey John, while this fixes the issue, we are now unable to reference the election landing page when there is an active election. Could we have either `/election` or `/election/-1` always displaying this landing page? Or perhaps just fix the wording when there is an active election?